# Google+ login via Sign In button: Trouble with persisting session across different pages, and displaying Login/Logout buttons

Tags: javascript, php, session, google-plus

My page /login.php displays the signin button and signs you in. So far I have managed to:

- Include relevant code in common files so that G+ signin code is present in all pages
- Moved stuff from the button element itself to  tags in the header
- Instead of keeping any significant logic in my signinCallback, I attached a callback function that is called on each page load, like this:

  po.src = '[https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=OnLoadCallback](https://apis.google.com/js/client%3aplusone.js?onload=OnLoadCallback)';
- I then made that function look like this:

  ```
  function OnLoadCallback(){
      var sessionParams = {
          'client_id': 'myapp-id-here',
          'session_state': null
      }
      gapi.auth.checkSessionState(sessionParams, function(stateMatched){
          if(stateMatched === true){
              console.log("You do not seem to be logged in!");
          }else{
              console.log("You should be logged in!");

              // Trigger request to get the email address.
              gapi.client.load('plus','v1', loadProfile);

              if(window.location.pathname === '/login.php'){
                  toggleElement('signin-button');
                  window.location = "/";
              }

          }
      }); 
  }
  ```

I found this bit of code regarding the session state in some article but I'm not sure it works as it's supposed to. In Chrome it seems more or less OK but in FF, when I first tried it, it should give me "not logged" in my console. Since I was logged in FF with my google account (but not in my app!), it seemed to recognize me as logged in, or at least my session was anything but the null (as stated in the code).

So, what should I use instead of "null" when it comes to determining session state?

Comment: Due to my lack of experience in this Google API, I incorrectly assumed there should be a special function that should be called on every page load that should check for user status. It turned out taking Google data-attributes away from the sign in button and placing them in form of meta tags (page based config) in the head section (included across pages) is sufficient enough. Now everything that should occur on signin/signout can be implemented in my signinCallback method defined in one of my meta tags. As simple as that (this is just for someone having hard times with the same issue).

Comment: Reference for later if you need it: http://wheresgus.com/signindemo